# Why is aiomqtt.error.MqttError: Operation timed out raised?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, mqtt, paho, periodic-task

I have a MQTT publisher module coded in Python 3.11.3 using aiomqtt 1.2.1. It's all based on asyncio tasks.

Whyt my code basically does is publishing a config_io message and after that publishing data_in messages. publishing the config_io works perfectly fine but after that a timeout error is thrown by aiomqtt: "wait_for
raise MqttError(msg) from None aiomqtt.error.MqttError: Operation timed out"

So the connection to the broker works and I think the problem is related to the periodic publishing which is included. I use the library asyncio-periodic 2019.2. Can somebody support me in finding the issue?

```
import aiomqtt
import asyncio
from periodic import Periodic
import datetime
from datetime import timezone
import json
import ssl
import sys
import os

def get_json_config_io():
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    Json_Config = {"last_edited":str(current_time),
                   "value":"test"}
    return json.dumps(Json_Config)

def get_json_pub():
    plc.open()
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
    data_pub={
        "Timestamp":utc_timestamp,
        "value":"test"
        }
    json_pub = json.dumps(data_pub)
    return json_pub

async def config_publishing(client):
    resource = 'config_io'
    topic = "$resource/" + resource 
    json_pub = get_json_config_io()
    await client.publish(topic,payload=json_pub)
    print("config_io published")

async def periodic_publishing(client):
    resource = 'data_in'
    topic = "$resource/" + resource 
    json_pub = get_json_pub()
    await client.publish(topic,payload=json_pub)
    print("data published")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    reconnect_interval = 5
    try:
        with open("iot_connector_fqdn.txt", "r") as connector_file:
            print("File 'iot_connector_fqdn.txt' found...")
            connector_fqdn = connector_file.read()
    except FileNotFoundError as exc:
        print("File 'iot_connector_fqdn.txt' not found...")
        connector_fqdn = input("IoT Connector FQDN? ")
        with open("iot_connector_fqdn.txt", "w") as connector_file:
            connector_file.write(connector_fqdn)
    token = open("./token.txt", "r").read()
    print("Using Token: {}\n".format(token))
    cert = "./DigiCertGlobalRootCA.cer"
    tls_params = aiomqtt.TLSParameters(ca_certs=cert,cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED)
    first_connection = True
    while True:
        try:
            async with aiomqtt.Client(hostname=connector_fqdn, port=8883, username='', password=token, client_id='', tls_params=tls_params) as client:
                pub_periodic = Periodic(30, periodic_publishing, client)
                if first_connection == True:
                    await config_publishing(client)
                    first_connection = False
                    await asyncio.sleep(5)
                    await pub_periodic.start(delay=0)
        except aiomqtt.MqttError as error:
            print(f'Error "{error}". Reconnecting in {reconnect_interval} seconds.')
            await asyncio.sleep(reconnect_interval) 

# Change to the "Selector" event loop if platform is Windows
if sys.platform.lower() == "win32" or os.name.lower() == "nt":
    from asyncio import set_event_loop_policy, WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy
    set_event_loop_policy(WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

asyncio.run(main())
```

I already verified that the confiG_io message is sent and published to the broker.
I tried to find another option for the periodic publishing but didn't find a suitable answer.

Comment: You are recreating `client` on every iteration of your loop (`while True:`); move this outside of the loop (see [this example](https://sbtinstruments.github.io/aiomqtt/reconnection.html)). It also looks like you need a way to wait for the connection to drop (I believe `await pub_periodic.start(delay=0)` will return almost immediately meaning you currently reconnect constantly - I suspect that a loop with a sleep would do the job, using [periodic](https://github.com/vd2org/periodic) adds complexity that appears unnecessary).